# NHibernate Stackoverflow exception in composite relationship

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, fluent-nhibernate, stack-overflow

I get a stackoverflow exception when trying to remove a composite object from a collection (but only when i wrap it inside a transaction). However getting the object and deleting it on the session, instead of the collection, and saving the parent works.

The code looks like this:

```
using (var session = sessionProvider.GetSession())
        {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var products = session.Query<MyObject>().Select(x => x.MyObjectId > 0).ToList();

                //Would fail 
                var variant = session.Query<MyObject>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "some name that exists");
                var parent = MyObject.Parent;

                parent.RemoveMyObject(variant);
                session.Save(parent);

                //Doesn't fail
                //session.Delete(variant);

                transaction.Commit();
            }
            session.Flush();
        }
```

And my mapping looks like this:

```
            HasMany(x => x.MyObject).AsSet().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Inverse().KeyColumn("MyObjectId").BatchSize(2000);
        References(x => x.MyObject).Column("MyObjectId");
```

What should i do to fix this ? It should work in both ways. And it is, as said, only when there's a transaction around. Both approaches works without a transaction.

Best regards
Morten